# AWS Elastic Beanstalk : the command eb list shows no environments

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I am using Elastic Beanstalk and I have created 3 different environments. I used awsebcli. All of a sudden the command `eb list` doesn't show me my enviroments because of which I am unable to deploy the environment. The error I am getting is `ERROR: This branch does not have a default environment. You must either specify an environment by typing "eb status my-env-name" or set a default environment by typing "eb use my-env-name".`
I tried `eb status 'my-env-name'`, again I got an error : `ERROR: The environment name 'my-env-name' could not be found.` In short: I am unable to use any `eb` command.

Comment: i figured at-least one thing that i am on wrong branch of the application. How can i change application i want to work on using eb commands ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message itself is clear. You haven't set an environment for the branch you are working on.

You can either switch to the branch it's configure, but this means the changes you have in the current branch won't be available on deploy, unless you merge thos changes or you can set an environment for the branch you currently are using the command `eb use name-of-your-env`. This last can also be configured in the Elastic Beanstalk configuration file of your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank @apineda , but I already tried eb use name-of-my-env . It says that my environment doesn't exist. I already know why its giving this error. Its because eb is on the wrong branch (application). I have to take eb on another application and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Oh with "wrong branch" you really mean wrong repository. It's a totally different application?

Comment: yeah I am in a different application. I want to switch to another application.

Comment: run `eb init` from the root of your app. Here's a link that gives you detail explanation of how to configure the deploy http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html.

Comment: It was missing IAM permission in my case. This helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038941/elastic-beanstalk-iam-developer-permissions

Answer (score 6):

Did you forgot to run `eb create --single` after `eb init`?

This command creates a new environment. See [EB CLI Command Reference »](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html)

Comment: I see that hathlogic says he created 3 environments. I hope my answer will help other searchers who visit this page.

Comment: i don't understand why this comand is not referenced at all in the amazon documentation. someone needs to tell them

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this may help others. I already had an existing environment on Beanstalk and was setting up a new Mac.

For some reason, the `eb init` did create a file in `~/.aws/config`. However, it only have key and secret. To get it to work, I need to add the region as well.

```
# ~/.aws/config 
[profile eb-cli]
aws_access_key_id = XXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXX
region=us-west-2
```

Next, I find my beanstalk config file in my application (i.e. project/.ebelasticbeanstalk/config.yml) and ensure that under global, it has profile: eb-cli

```
# project/.ebelasticbeanstalk/config.yml
global:
  default_region: us-west-2
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

After making those edits, `eb list` shows the environment I am expecting and I can do `eb deploy` again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue here. It turned out being a region related trick.

In my case, it initially seems like related to the way I created the environment. I used the following command to create the env:

```
eb create --sample -r ap-southeast-1 -im 2 -ix 4 --vpc.elbpublic --vpc.ec2subnets AppSubA, AppSubB --vpc.dbsubnets DbSubA, DbSubB node-express-dev
```

Note that I created the env in Singapore region. After that, if I use "eb list", the result is empty. Why? I will touch upon it later.

However, if I use the command like this:

```
eb create --sample node-express-env
```

The "eb list" will be able to find the created env.

For the 1st cmd, as I said, it was created in Singapore. However, before the creation, in the "eb init" cmd, I didn't specify region. So, "eb cli" is by default in us-west-2. That's why it cannot list the created env. To fix it, before the creation, the command
`eb init -p "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.5.3 running Node.js 16" --region ap-southeast-1` should be perfomed.

For the 2nd cmd, it is created in us-west-2, and "eb cli" is also in the same region. Both are in the default region. As a result, it can show it.

Hopefully this can help some cases.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've launched EB environment with AWS web console.

- Previous environment A
- New environment B

I was using eb cli with A(previous environment).

- eg. `eb deploy`

And I want to change my eb cli environment into B(new environment). However several commands not working for me(Never show environment B).

- `eb init`
- `eb list`

Finally, I removed `.elasticbeanstalk` directory and succeeded `eb init`.
I think EB has lots of unstable issues for its custom setting.