# I can't see my elasticbeanstalk application in the browser

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I have followed AWS's instructions for deploying a django application using the `ebcli`.

It is important to note, I think, that after running `eb init` I am prompted to select a reigon, enter my credentials, and set my instance. Afterwhich I receive feedback that my application has been created. I checked the AWS console on the browser and I see nothing. Yes, I checked all regions.

I found out that after doing `eb list` and `eb status` that the environment wasn't actually created in the `eb init` step so I referenced this answer: [AWS Elastic Beanstalk : the command eb list shows no environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616316/aws-elastic-beanstalk-the-command-eb-list-shows-no-environments)

Running `eb create --single` allowed the application to upload and I could access via the link provided. However, this for some reason is not attached to the instances in my user and cannot see it in the browser. Why is it that I cannot see my application in the AWS console despite it existing and running currently?

Here is the output of `eb status`

```
Environment details for: ****
  Application name: *****
  Region: *****
  Deployed Version: app-2ecd-200609_120851
  Environment ID: e-wbqx6*****
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-northeast-1::platform/Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.2
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: *****.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2020-**-** 03:18:12.491000+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Green
```

Comment: Are you sure you are deploying to the same account using CLI as the account you use in Console?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, in the sense that I provided my credentials like the SECRET and ID. There isn't a great way to confirm this just using the ebcli, however

Comment: the only possible mixup could be, it asks for `aws-access-id` and `aws-secret-key` and i may have thought that the access-id was the same as the access key id provided with the credentials. I believe this is correct, however, as I saw someone do it from a video and just copied them

Comment: and when you use aws cli [describe-environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-environments.html) can you find your EB env, or it also does not show like in console?

Comment: i think i resolved it. it turns out that there was an existing ~/.aws/config that was being used

Comment: Glad to hear. So it was different account after all? If so, I can make an answer for future reference?

Comment: yes, ended up being a different account completely. sorry

Comment: No problem. I added the answer for future reference. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: @frei it be polite to accept the answer considering the time was taken to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was the use of **different account** in `eb cli` and `aws console`.

The solution was to use the same account.

Answer (score 0):

Or check your region it should be the same in console and in CLI

Environment details for: ****

Application name: *****

Region: ***** <+======================

Comment: This question was already answered. In the comment section it was determined that the beanstalk application was deployed to the wrong account. Please avoid answering old questions that have been answered.