# AWS EB CLI does not show recently created application/environment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I used the Web to create a new application/environment, and it uses the same Service role and EC2 key pair/profile as my previous environments. The new environment is active and running.

When I look on my console to see all of my environments (https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=us-west-2#/environments) it shows up.

When I use the CLI, I see the 5 other environments I created over the years, but not this new environment. I have tried `eb use <EnvName>` and `eb init` (this command only lists the 5 old environments).

My `~/.aws/config` has my profile and region set, and my `~/.aws/credentials` are set. Any ideas on what I'm missing? Is it some new permission [that my profile does not have?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33979816/277601) Why do my other environments show up (I can `eb config save` and everything else for those 5 environments)?

Potentially related, but didn't seem to help: [AWS Elastic Beanstalk : the command eb list shows no environments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42616316/277601)

Thanks